# Build jar with dependency that has different version on the cluster

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, dependencies, xgboost

I am building a fat jar using Maven (have tried gradle too) locally. My code is in scala and it is using spark. For one of the dependencies (xgboost4j-spark) I use version 0.82 to build the jar, but on the cluster that I am running this jar I have version 0.72. I run it as

`spark-submit --class <MainClass> code.jar`

When run it on the cluster, it is using version 0.72, although in the jar I should have version 0.82.

Why it doesn't use the version that I have built the jar with?

Comment: That is because, the classes from 0.72 is getting picked up in the classpath before the classes of 0.82 that are in your fat jar.

Comment: So how can I change that?

Comment: You'll have to get that jar removed from the cluster.

Comment: Which jar? The jar for version 0.72?

Comment: Yes. You’ll have to remove 0.72 version jar.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this without removing the previous version from the cluster. I don't have the admin privilege to do that.

Comment: Pass the 0.82 version jar while submitting your job.  the jar that passes through command line is supposed to get the top priority.

Comment: That's not working! It is still using 0.72.